# Transparent texture not fully opaque

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I am trying to add a transparent texture to my particles, to get some blending.

[Particles are here](http://marky.pl/vu/vf/)

After zooming in you will can see that the texture is just not fully transparent - black square is still visible?

Any ideas how to fix it? (yes, transparency: true is set:))

Comment: Could you add some explanation on how your texture is formed? this webpage is not the most fun to inspect (although it is fun to look at).

Comment: `var pTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./texture.png');

 var pMaterial = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({size: 0.03, vertexColors: true, map: pTexture, transparent: true, blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending});` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices.

```
particleSystem.sortParticles = true;
```

It works, but a better solution in your case is:

```
particleMaterial.alphaTest = 0.5; // or whatever number between 0 and 1 works best
```

three.js r.65